# Error in playing audio through streaming

Tags: html, firefox, audio

Hi I am playing audio through streaming using object tag and it was working fine in chrome but not working in firefox.

I tried out the following HTML code to play 
I also tried audio tag but it is also not playing in firefox

Can anyone suggest me other types which support to play streaming audio

```
<object data="http://50.79.137.37:9440/;" type="application/x-mplayer2"></object>
```

Comment: Is there any live website or jsfiddle where we can see your code?

Comment: i had kept streaming url

Comment: Doesn't serve the sufficient purpose. Need to know your code.

Comment: if your audio file is MP4 format, then FFF and opera won't support it btw. A best workaround is to use flash player with it. It loads a tad longer, but supports all browsers except iOS browsers.

Comment: actually i am using stream url not the file it was played by stream url as i mentioned i above code